# Where can I find a Leaf Stone?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I've been playing through Pokemon Crystal on my phone, and it's time for me to face the Elite Four. My team is alright at this point, but I've been stepping on egg-shells for a while now; I've got an Exeggcute. Sadly, this little collection of fragile eggs needs a Leaf Stone to become a BBP (Big Beautiful Pineapple...), but I can't seem to find one that is available BEFORE the Elite Four.

Where can I find a Leaf Stone before fighting the Elite Four?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there are three ways to get a Leaf Stone in Crystal specifically. From [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/gbc/375087-pokemon-crystal-version/answers/94313-where-can-i-find-a-leaf-stone):

> In Crystal, there are three ways to get a Leaf Stone:
>
> 1. Show Bill's Gramps an Oddish.
> 2. Get the Picnicker's Phone number on Route 34, and somtimes she will call and give you a Leaf Stone when you talk to [her].
> 3. You can also get one from Mystery Gift (very Rare).

Comment: Ahh okay, Bill's Gramps is in Kanto, so I can't quite get there. Looks like it's waiting for Gina to call for me...

Comment: @Kaizerwolf based on the info [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/gbc/375087-pokemon-crystal-version/answers/257042-where-can-i-find-all-the-stone) it seems like the Leaf Stone is one of the hardest to find...

Comment: Just my luck for deciding to use an Exeggute I guess...